# Yearly once-off in-app subscription (app store)

Tags: ios, xcode, subscription, in-app

I am making an app which offers an auto-renewable in-app subscription which charges a specific tier per month. I also need to make a once-off discounted year payment subscription.

I see on apple's website (https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/) that this is doable:
[image: Year subscription]

I also see the recommended in-app subscription for this kind of usage:
[image: Year subscription]

But once I add the in-app purchase and go to edit mode, I cannot see anywhere referring to a year plan or anything else.

Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it is a non-renewing subscription then it is up to you to compute the period and expiration date, however by combining auto renewing and non-renewing subscription products your users won't be able to take advantage of the new upgrade/downgrade functionality that is shown in your screen shot

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11 . That means that:

1. The user can buy the non-renewing subscription for let's say $29,90
2. He gets charged ONCE and not monthly
3. I verify the receipt and when the year ends I invalidate it myself from within the app or via a server ?

Comment: That is correct.  I don't know why you wouldn't use an auto-renewing subscription for both options.  That way the expiration date is tracked for you in the receipt and the user has the option to upgrade/downgrade at the conclusion of each subscription period.

Comment: You are right about using auto-renewing subscriptions, but with auto-renewing subscriptions will I be able to charge the user again a once-off payment of the whole price? Or will he be charged with a fraction of the amount per month? Apple is so not-detailed on the in-app purchase documentation

Comment: For an annual subscription they are charged the full amount once per year. It is also better to use auto-renewing subscriptions as Apple reduces their commission after the first year.  This reduction does not occur with non-renewing subscriptions.

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11 for your precious insight! Do you want to answer on the question so that I can mark it as correct answer?

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to this... for example:

- User purchases a yearly subscription: All Access - 1 year.
- After a month or two, user realizes he likes monthly better and downgrades to All Access - 1 month.

What happens to the revenue? Did the user pay 48.99 the first month, then gets refunded for 48.99 - (amount used * 48.99)? How is that shown in iTunes Connect?